# Database Connection PHPBB

Tags: web-applications, database-connection, phpbb, phpbb3

In web applications like phpBB, when every time a new page is requested, is a new database connection created?

For example when 5 users login using login.php simultaneously, is a new database connection created for each of the five users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not support connection pooling. phpBB does have the option of using mysql_pconnect. pconnect however is not pooling, but a primitive form of re-sharing a database connection. Related: [Connection pooling in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753/connection-pooling-in-php)

To answer your question: Yes, PHP applications open a new connection each time.