# Connection pooling in php to call webservice

Tags: php, multithreading, web-services, mutex, connection-pooling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connection pooling in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753/connection-pooling-in-php)

I want to establish a connection to a webservice and it allows only 10 concurrent connections to the webservice url.  I need to manage a pool of 10 objects in php which will request this webservice. How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there are no tutorials out there on how to accomplish this.

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's not a suitable duplicate -- it deals exclusively with database connections (primarily in the context of mysql).