# how to avoid connecting to mysql database with every request in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, pdo

i have a simple php page that query the database for a random row (with some exceptions), every time it gets a post request.

i have noticed that the post request take some time to get the response.

**because with every post request it reconnect to mysql server**, so i thought maybe i could store the pdo in $_SESSION and use it to save some time and not have to authenticate with every request

i don't know if there is any way to fix this :)

```
<?php
// check for POST Request Only
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
    exit();
}
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'Quiz';
$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

    if (!empty($_POST['old'])) {
        $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($_POST['old']) - 1) . '?';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM QT WHERE id NOT IN ($in) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute($_POST['old']);
        $data = $stm->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();

    } else {
        $stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM QT ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
        $stm->execute();
        $data = $stm->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();

    }
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

?>

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, but this is related to: [Connection pooling in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753/connection-pooling-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Сonnecting to mysql database with every request is how

## PHP intended to work

Nothing wrong here, nothing to optimize here.

Go connect on every request and next time try to optimize a real issue.

> so i thought

Don't *think*. **Measure**.

From the experience I can tell you that its the query that takes the time, not the connection. But technically that would be a guess all the same. So you have to **measure** first, then get the **real** issue, then **google** for it, solutions are plenty.

But measure first.